# title or caption of schema

Tags: tikz-pgf

can I add a title to this schema? 
if i use `\caption{\textbf{\label {}The multilevel of the abstraction}}` I have pb. and thanksssssssssssss

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[edges]{forest}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=left}
    [Ontological models and languages\\ 
    for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
    on the Semantic Web 
     [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
      [Terminological Ressources
       [Vocabularies
        [The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
       ]
       [pft112
        [pft1121]
        [pft1122]
       ]  
      ]
      [pft12
       [pft121
        [pft1211]
       ]
       [pft122
        [pft1221]
       ]  
       [pft123
        [pft1231]
       ]  
      ]
     ]
     [pft2
      [pft21
       [pft211]
       [pft212]  
      ]
      [pft22]
     ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I have pb"? Could you please also add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you've tried so far?

Comment: like title of table

Comment: Table 1. Extract from the original concepts table.

Comment: or for figure Figure 1. E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this but you need to put the thing in a `table` or `figure` environment to make use of `\caption`. And you may not use the `standalone` class for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{\textbf{The multilevel of the abstraction.}\label{fig:tree}}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=left,
}
[Ontological models and languages\\ 
for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
on the Semantic Web 
 [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
  [Terminological Ressources
   [Vocabularies
    [The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
   ]
   [pft112
    [pft1121]
    [pft1122]
   ]  
  ]
  [pft12
   [pft121
    [pft1211]
   ]
   [pft122
    [pft1221]
   ]  
   [pft123
    [pft1231]
   ]  
  ]
 ]
 [pft2
  [pft21
   [pft211]
   [pft212]  
  ]
  [pft22]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious, why not `standalone`?

Comment: @pushpen.paul It is not made for floats, but it seemed to me that the OP might be interested in some regular document that really supports them.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using the caption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=left}
[Ontological models and languages\\ 
for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
on the Semantic Web 
 [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
  [Terminological Ressources
   [Vocabularies
    [The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
   ]
   [pft112
    [pft1121]
    [pft1122]
   ]  
  ]
  [pft12
   [pft121
    [pft1211]
   ]
   [pft122
    [pft1221]
   ]  
   [pft123
    [pft1231]
   ]  
  ]
 ]
 [pft2
  [pft21
   [pft211]
   [pft212]  
  ]
  [pft22]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\captionof{figure}{foo}
\end{document}
```